# How to enable locked user again on laravel after 3 wrong attempts on login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello i am using the following code security and it is working. But I wanted to know how to enable the lock account again as per code:

```
if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return redirect('/login')->withErrors(array('error' => 'Your account has been disabled because of too many wrong attempts'));
        }
```

```
        //check if user is deactivated by admin
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email_username)->first();
        if ($user && !$user->active) {
            return redirect('/login')->withErrors(array('error' => 'Your account has been disabled by an administrator.'));
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return redirect('/login')->withErrors(array('error' => 'Your account has been disabled because of too many wrong attempts'));
        }

        if(isset($user) && !empty($user)){
            $request->session()->forget('password_expired_id');

            $password_updated_at = $user->passwordSecurity->password_updated_at;
            $password_expiry_days = $user->passwordSecurity->password_expiry_days;
            $password_expiry_at = Carbon::parse($password_updated_at)->addDays($password_expiry_days);
            if($password_expiry_at->lessThan(Carbon::now()) || $user->force_reset == "1"){
                $request->session()->put('password_expired_id',$user->id);
                auth()->logout();
                return redirect('/passwordExpiration')->with('message', "Your Password is expired, You need to change your password.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the build-in authentication, you can add the `maxAttempts` property to the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` and assign it to `3`.

There is a build-in throttling, but if you need to write a custom logic, you can `override` the `sendLockoutResponse()` method (again inside the `LoginController`) or listen for the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout` event.

Keep in mind that locking the user's account may not be a good idea since any user can lock any other user's account...

[reference](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/after-three-login-failed-attempts-i-need-to-lock-the-user-account)